# Extend a Laravel model that always attaches a `where status = 'cancelled'` to select statements?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I'm working with Laravel and [Nova](https://nova.laravel.com/).  So basically in Laravel, I have a model like this:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
}
```

Then, Nova helps me create a nice CMS web interface at `https://example.com/admin/resouces/flights` that lists all my flights and `https://example.com/admin/resouces/flights/<id>` to let me CRUD against a particular record.  All I have to do to make this happen is create the file `app/Nova/Flight.php` with the content:

```
<?php

namespace App\Nova;

//... import other classes like Text Fields, WYSIWYG editors etc.. etc.., that are the nice CMS UI fields to modify each column in my flights table

class Flight extends Resource
{
    public static $model = 'App\Flight';
    // ... list of fields I want to modify ...
}
```

This works fine and all, except now I want to make two different urls like:

```
* `https://example.com/admin/resouces/flights-cancelled` - this should only list the equivalent of `SELECT * FROM flights WHERE status = 'cancelled'`
* `https://example.com/admin/resouces/flights-active` - this should only list the equivalent of `SELECT * FROM flights WHERE status = 'active'`
```

Things will get a bit more complicated as my project evolves, so I was wondering if there's a way to define a new model called `App\FlightCancelled` that is exactly the same as `App\Flight`, except all queries to the database will always include a `WHERE status='cancelled'` condition.  That way I can assign `App\FlightCancelled` as the model to my Nova resource.

Curious how that's done?  Or if there's a better way to achieve my objective?

Comment: does [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#local-scopes) cant fulfill your need? using one flight model, then do `Flight::cancelled()` for cancelled one.

Comment: That looks promising, will try that out

Answer (score 1):

You can modify `$table` and override `newQuery()` - the method that Eloquent use to construct a new query.

**FlightCancelled**

```
protected $table = 'flights'

public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true)
{
    return parent::newQuery($excludeDeleted)
        ->where('status', '=', 'cancelled');
}
```

---

In this case, I recommend using [lenses](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/lenses/defining-lenses.html), allow you to fully customize the underlying resource Eloquent query.

```
class FlightCancelled extends Lens
{
    public static function query(LensRequest $request, $query)
    {
        // Query here..
    }

    //
}
```